# angular issue consuming JSON of certian formatting

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to ng-repeat over 'cols' as a starting point. But I'm getting an error when trying to consume this JSON

```
{
"cols":["id","name","type"],
"rows":[
    ["284","JAMES DEAN","Employee"],
    ["243","Brian J Adamms","Employee"],
    ["237","Test Account","Brokerage Account"],
    ["241","Robert Borkman","guest"]
  ]
}
```

The error appears to be in the angularJS file, but Im sure the problem is elsewhere.

```
Error: a.push is not a function 
W@http://127.0.0.1/js/lib/angular.min.js:10 
g@http://127.0.0.1/js/lib/angular-resource.min.js:7 
u/</g[b]/</<@http://127.0.0.1/js/lib/angular-resource.min.js:8 
o@http://127.0.0.1/js/lib/angular.min.js:7 
u/</g[b]/<@http://127.0.0.1/js/lib/angular-resource.min.js:8 
Rc/e/g.promise.then/i@http://127.0.0.1/js/lib/angular.min.js:79 
Rc/e/g.promise.then/i@http://127.0.0.1/js/lib/angular.min.js:79 
Rc/f/<.then/<@http://127.0.0.1/js/lib/angular.min.js:79 
e.prototype.$eval@http://127.0.0.1/js/lib/angular.min.js:91 
e.prototype.$digest@http://127.0.0.1/js/lib/angular.min.js:89 
e.prototype.$apply@http://127.0.0.1/js/lib/angular.min.js:91 
f@http://127.0.0.1/js/lib/angular.min.js:100 
B@http://127.0.0.1/js/lib/angular.min.js:103 
ad/</p.onreadystatechange@http://127.0.0.1/js/lib/angular.min.js:105
```

Here is a "plunker" example - run console - you'll see the same error I'm getting - and the JSON shows as an empty array.

http://plnkr.co/edit/QgNkvsOIVzrpUp5pP02p?p=preview

Thank you all for help

Comment: Could you show your code, and if possible create a jsFiddle replicating the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the error is in angular source, and it will handle that JSON just fine: http://plnkr.co/edit/knJQ0S?p=preview

Comment: cool plnkr - thx, I may try it out and put the whole code so you can see where my sticking point is - thx to you and ajay - it's NOT the JSON... someplace else.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/a3NNLe?p=preview This shows getting the data with $resource and with $http.

Comment: Ah - very good - looks like I missed passing in some stuff on the $resource{} - and much thanks for the $http example, I "struggled" with using the $resource, and loosing the granularity - but seeing them together, $resource is a great economy of syntax. Thank you Sharon.

Answer (score 1):

Im able to get what problem you are facing see the below code

```
 <html ng-app="myapp" >

  <head lang="en">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Custom Plunker</title>

    <script src="Scripts/Angular.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body >
<div ng-controller="TestCtrl" >
   <div ng-repeat="data in data.cols">
       {{data}}
   </div>
</div>
        <script>
            var myapp = angular.module('myapp', []);



            function TestCtrl($scope, $http,$timeout) {
                $scope.data = {
                    "cols": ["id", "name", "type"],
                    "rows": [
                        ["284", "JAMES DEAN", "Employee"],
                        ["243", "Brian J Adamms", "Employee"],
                        ["237", "Test Account", "Brokerage Account"],
                        ["241", "Robert Borkman", "guest"]
                    ]
                };


            }


  </script>     
  </body>



</html>
```

Comment: Yes -excellent, and thanks for pointing out this way of getting at a problem.... your example works, and Shannon is correct too.. IF I put that JSON directly as the return of my controller it works...HOWEVER this means the $resource is affecting the returned JSON coming back from my data store - OR my data store is 'adding' stuff... wen I view the HTTP response in firebug, the JSON is what I'd expect - (see addendum above)

Comment: try one thing just put your json in text file and then use resource to fetch from the the text file and see the behaviour